# How to pass data back to the same page

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

My objective is to pass data to the same page. I am having trouble understanding the concept. I'm still new to ionic btw.

My `request.html` code retrieves the all the request from the request firebase console.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title name="title">Job Requests</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="filter">
<button class="islandwide" ion-button large>Islandwide</button>
<button class="nearby" ion-button large (click)="openMapPage()">Nearby</button>
 </div>

<ion-list>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let user of request | async" class="job">
     <button ion-item (click)="goToJobDetails(user.$key)" class="info">
    <ion-avatar class="avatar" item-start>
        <img src="../assets/icon/user_male-512.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2 class="name">{{user.regdetails.username}}</h2>
    <p text-wrap class="address"><ion-icon name="compass">
         </ion-icon> {{user.regdetails.address}}</p>
    <p id="key">{{user.$key}}</p>
     </button> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

My constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
            angFire: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.request = angFire.list('/request');
    this.userreq = angFire.list(`${this.userkey}`);
    this.reqdetails = angFire.list('reqdetails');

  }
```

My `openMapPage()` method

Basically this method returns all the users who only have `reqdetails`, and the data is pass back to the `request.html` page

```
openMapPage()
  {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
            if (reqdetails) {

                this.data = requestKey;
                console.log(this.data);
                //this.arr.push(requestKey);
                //console.log(this.arr);
            }

        });
        this.navCtrl.push(RequestsPage, { 'param1': this.data });
    });


}
```

This is what the `request.html` will look like after it gets all the data from the request table. This is the default view meaning it gets all the request records from firebase.

[image]

And now I am facing this issue. When a user clicks and triggers my `openMapPage()` method in `request.html` it will redirect to `openMapPage`. How do I redirect the data for the user who only has `reqdetails`, to the same html page `request.html`

I have tried this so far

```
this.navCtrl.push(RequestsPage, { 'param1': this.data });
```

But it is still showing the whole request, meaning it has not been filtered.

Comment: what is your `console.log(this.data);` prints

Comment: It's prints out all the user key that has only reqdetails.

Comment: How do i pass back to the request.html page ?

Comment: i meant after the user clicks on the nearby button it goes to the openMapPage method then it get it's data and display to the request.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's solved.

```
openMapPage()
  {


   var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
            if (reqdetails) {
                this.data = requestKey;
                console.log(this.data);
                //this.arr.push(requestKey);
                //console.log(this.arr);
                 this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
                   query: {
                   orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
                   startAt: 'reqdetails'
            }
         })   

            }
        });
/*        this.navCtrl.push(RequestsPage, {
            thing1: this.data
         });*/

        //this.navCtrl.push(RequestsPage, { 'param1': this.data });
    });     
  }
```